# How to deploy Laravel project that requires Redis service on Shared Hosting

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, redis

i'm trying to deploy [laravel-tricks](https://github.com/CodepadME/laravel-tricks) project on godaddy shared hosting.
which does not have any support [redis service](http://redis.io/topics/quickstart) 
and this project usages redis for cache and others optimization
is there any way to use this project without redis service.

currently getting error

```
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. [tcp://127.0.0.1:6379]
```

on localhost it's working properly with redis service install.
is there any way to get this working on shared hosting.?

Laravel Framework version 4.1.31

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add or edit in your  .env  file

```
REDIS_HOST=localhost
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

you need to change the redis_host , password and port with those that u have on ur shared hosting ( i think you should use a vps or a hosted redis server )

edit your config/cache.php

```
'default' => env('CACHE_DRIVER', 'file'),
```

and add this if you dont have it already on ur env file

```
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
```

and remove redis variables from the .env

Comment: what you think is right .. but i'm trying to use this project on shared hosting not i'm planning to use any hosted server as my budget is a bit low..

Comment: if there is a way to disable redis functionality in this project that will help

Comment: Does Laravel 4.1.31 supports .env files  i con't find any ?

Comment: no it dosent i guess, just to to  app/config/cache.php make sure Driver set to file   like this     'driver' => 'file',

Comment: try to remove this from app/config/database.php               ->  'redis' => array(

  'cluster' => false,

  'default' => array(
   'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
   'port'     => 6379,
   'database' => 0,
  ),

 ),

Comment: are you sure that the redis package is not installed and the app is not using redis at first?

Comment: redis is install and app is using it even i don't wants it to be used ..  whenever i'm trying to remove  redis array from database.php  getting ErrorException
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Redis\Database::__construct() must be of the type array, null given,

Comment: thanks for your help and time finally got it working..  problem was with session.php  file it was also using redis for cache that's why app was using it every time.

Comment: glad that you found the solution, sorry for not being accurate but i never used laravel 4